# Onscroll на textarea

Tags: javascript

Функция должна увеличивать высоту поля, когда текста начинает выходить за пределы поля. Проблема в том, что события  срабатывает 2 раза, а надо 1, как например в Google+

```
textarea.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        height += 12
        console.log('change size textarea' + height)
        textarea.style.height =  height + 'px'
},false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, у меня всё нормально: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/onejoq/1/).

```
textarea.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
        var newHeight = parseFloat(this.style.height) + 12;
        console.log('change size textarea ' + this.style.height + ' to '+ newHeight);
        this.style.height =  newHeight + 'px';
},false);
```

Comment: @Zhukov Roman

change size textarea  to NaN :O

Comment: @lampa, какой браузер?

Comment: @Zhukov Roman посмотрите внимательнее, там иного срабатывает за два раза

Comment: @Zhukov Roman firefox 20.0.1

Comment: @lampa растини, у меня тоже так

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
document.getElementById('textarea').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    console.log(this.scrollHeight);
    this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 10 +  'px';
},false);
```

Comment: @lampa он все равно выполняет обработчик 2 раза, а должен один. Не успевает меняться ширина

Comment: Ну он и будет выполняться 2 раза. Первый раз это когда происходит системный скролл, а второй раз - когда мы изменяем его.

Comment: @lampa, а как сделать, что-бы он выполнялся только один раз?